# Does drinking juice help to remove toxins?

Tags: nutrition

This article [Colon Cleansing – 3 Recipes Creating a Buzz](http://www.juicecleansehq.com/colon-cleansing/) includes 4 (sic) recipes that "cleanse the colon" to "get rid of any sort of harmful toxins".

> - Apple Juice High Fiber Colon Cleansing Recipe
> - Lemon Ginger Colon Cleansing Recipe
> - Papaya and Flaxseed Colon Cleansing Recipe
> - Colon Cleansing Soup Recipe
>
> Every one of these are types of a natural colon cleanse recipes that you can attempt to be able to obtain a nice relief from constipation, and to get rid of any sort of harmful toxins or excess materials which may be clogging up your colon.

Does juice help to get rid of any sort of harmful toxins?

Comment: I think the point of a juice fast doesn't lie in drinking juice but in not eating anything solid but still getting your calories.

Comment: A common aspect of this sort of claim is that it does not specify *which* toxins it removes from your colon.  In order to refute the claim, studies must be found in which every possible substance that could be considered *toxic* is observed in the colon and then not observed after the treatment. Any chance you can find a more specific claim?

Comment: I suppose the answer is trivially 'yes' unless we add some implied claims, for example "better than water" ... is juice better than water at removing toxins?

Comment: @Ladadadada Wouldn't "get rid of any sort of harmful toxins" mean any toxic substance present in the colon can be removed by this?

Comment: @AdamPhelps I think the question means *can it remove at least one toxin?* rather than *can it remove all possible toxins?*.  Disproving the latter is easy.

Comment: Some juices, e.g. prune juice, are noted for their use as laxatives, which could be likened to detoxication.  I suspect that this is where the juice-for-detox idea gets its support and perhaps where it originally came from.

Answer (score 8):

Per a [report](http://senseaboutscience.org/activities/debunking-detox/) by Voice for Young Science for evidence behind the claims made about detox products and diets regarding 15 products that were sold in a range of mainstream supermarkets and pharmacies including foot pads, diet supplements and hair straighteners, the conclusion was "‘detox’, as used in product marketing, is a myth and worryingly many of the claims about how the body works were wrong and in some cases the suggested remedies were potentially dangerous".

They also found,

1. No two companies seem to use the same definition of ‘detox’.
2. Little, and in most cases no, evidence was offered to back up the detox claims.
3. In the majority of cases, producers and retailers contacted by the young scientists were forced to admit that they are renaming mundane things, like cleaning or brushing, as ‘detox’.

The Voice of Young Science team also compiled a detox dossier and a ‘anti detox’ leaflet which can be accessed [here](http://www.senseaboutscience.org/data/files/resources/48/Detox-Dossier-Embargoed-until-0001-5th-jan-2009.pdf) and <s>here</s> (link now goes to page not found error) in response to misleading claims about 'detox'.